# Where is the MediaWiki code generating the table of contents (TOC)?

Tags: mediawiki

I am using `mediawiki`.

I would like to create a custom version of the summary of a page. For this, I would like to modify the commands defining the default summary.

**Where can I find the commands creating the default summary are?**

**Where is the file in which the summary is implemented?**

[image]

Comment: You're not looking for the summary, but for the [table of contents](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Table_of_contents)

Answer (score 1):

The [table of contents/TOC](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Table_of_contents) AKA index is generated in the infamous [Parser.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Parser.php), inside `formatHeadings()` ([see current location](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/diffusion/MW/browse/master/includes/parser/Parser.php;0b4208e645b7945bebe3faa480f8b67eaa764b9c$4379)).